# Printing from an ASP.Net application server

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

Greetings,
we are a the moment developing a website for intranet use. The user should be able to select a pdf which already exists from a list and then hit the print button. When he hits the button the document should get printed by the webserver to a specific printer which the user also selects prior to hitting the button.

Does anyone have a solution on how to make the webserver print to a network printer by ipaddress? Language used is C#, server is windows 2008 with IIS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fire off acrobat.  Take a look at [this page](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2008/04/14/printing-pdf-documents-in-c.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this. Actually the code there doesnt work anymore but i came across a command for the command line there which works just perfectly.
This works:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Programs\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe","/t C:\test.pdf \\Server\Printer");

Thank you!